# How to use grep to filter out lines containing a specific number

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I want to use grep to filter a txt file. I just want lines containing number 35. I use grep command:

```
grep -iE "35" File.txt
```

and I get a result txt which contains many strings like:

```
9.335837
nal.cpp:3517
```

These strings contain "35", but that's not what I want. I just want number "35". But strings like:

```
fd=35
FD:35
ID 35,
```

are OK too. What grep command will help me do that?

Comment: `grep -iE '\b35\b' File.txt` or `grep -iE '\<35\>' File.txt`

Comment: Or with GNU grep: `grep -w '35' File.txt`. Take a look at `man grep`.